# How do I get all the URLs from my Wordpress site?

Tags: permalinks

I see in the database where my link normally is:

```
http://www.voomka.com/product/audio-and-video/samsung-ua55hu7000u-uhd-series-7-led-tv/
```

In the database, it shows only

```
samsung-ua55hu7000u-uhd-series-7-led-tv
```

In the "post_name" field. Which means there is some other logic that derives the full path.

I need all "products" posts, full path and model number. Is there an easy way to extract this?

Comment: There are many [sitemap plugins](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20sitemap%20plugin) that will do crawl all the links for you in an `xml` sitemap.

Comment: `get_permalink( $post_id )`

Answer (score 2):

I used the WooCommerce API and this code:

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);

    // Include the client library
    require_once 'class-wc-api-client.php';

    $consumer_key = 'XXXX'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
    $consumer_secret = 'XXXX'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here
    $store_url = 'http://www.example.com/'; // Add the home URL to the store you want to connect to here

    // Initialize the class
    $wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );

    $file = './dataX.txt';

    if (file_exists($file) ) {
        $products = file_get_contents($file);
    }
    else {
        $itemsPerPage = 15;
        $page = 0;
        $p = $wc_api->get_products(array( 'filter[limit]' => $itemsPerPage, 'filter[offset]' => ($page * $itemsPerPage) ) );
        $products = array();
        while (!empty($p->products)) {
            foreach ($p->products as $pppp) {
                $products[] = $pppp;
            }
            $page++;
            $p = $wc_api->get_products(array( 'filter[limit]' => $itemsPerPage, 'filter[offset]' => ($page * $itemsPerPage) ) );
    }
    print '<pre>';
    print sizeof($products).'----'; 
    print_r($products);
    die();
```